# Does Integrating Jmeter for Azure CI/CD pipeline tests needs Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, performance-testing, cicd

Do we need jenkins to integrate jmeter for Azure pipeline tests? Or Without Jenkins, can we upload scripts to GitHub and run pipeline tests?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jenkins, Azure Pipelines is Microsoft's [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) solution

So you can run JMeter as:

- Simple [Shell Script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script?view=azure-devops) (but in that case you need to install JMeter on the machine which will be running the task beforehand). JMeter [command-line execution](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) is pretty straightforward
- [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops), in this case you need to come up with a [Maven pom.xml file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) and Maven will download and install JMeter for you